# using autocomplete with commas in a field

Tags: coldfusion, autocomplete

I'm trying to use autocomplete with a field with commas in it. When I type the comma it will ignore it, and won't return anything. So far I have this:

index.cfm

```
<!--- A simple form for auto suggest --->
<cfform action="autosuggest.cfm" method="post">
  Artist: 
  <cfinput type="text" name="artist" size="50" autosuggest="cfc:autosuggest.findartist({cfautosuggestvalue})" autosuggestminlength="4" maxresultsdisplayed="5" /><br /><br />
</cfform>
```

autosuggest.cfc

```
<cfcomponent output="false">

    <!--- Lookup used for auto suggest --->
    <cffunction name="findartist" access="remote" returntype="string">
        <cfargument name="search" type="any" required="false" default="">

        <!--- Define variables --->
        <cfset var local = {} />

        <!--- Query Location Table --->
        <cfquery name="local.query" datasource="#application.datasource#" >
            select      DISTINCT artist
            from        items
            where       artist like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ucase(arguments.search)#%" />
            order by    artist
        </cfquery>

        <!--- And return it as a List --->
        <cfreturn valueList(local.query.artist)>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

When I try to search for example Brown,James it doesn't return anything. What do I need to put in it to return results with commas.

Thanks

Comment: Well, you might want to tag your question with the relevant programming language and tools.

Comment: @Kay and also please post your rendered HTML as well.

Comment: If you put your term directly into the query with a comma, does it return results?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to have your function return an array, instead of a string. Then delimiters are not an issue.

```
   <cffunction name="findartist" access="remote" returntype="array">
      ...
      <cfreturn listToArray(valueList(local.query.artist, chr(30)), chr(30))>
   </cffunction>
```

Update:

As Raymond pointed out, the only sure-fire way to avoid delimiter issues on the CF side is not to use them.  Instead loop through the query to build the array, ie:

```
   <cffunction name="findartist" access="remote" returntype="array">
       ...
       <cfset local.arr = []>
       <cfloop query="local.query">
           <cfset arrayAppend(local.arr, local.query.artist)>
       </cfloop>

       <cfreturn local.arr>
   </cffunction>
```

Comment: If the OP is reading this, note that use of chr(30) as a delimiter.  That takes care of commas in the data.

Comment: Why bother with delimiters? Just loop over the query and create an array. That way you never have to worry about chr(30) being in the data (although that is probably never going to happen).

Comment: @RaymondCamden - No particular reason. I was just in an anti-looping mood ;-). But agreed looping is more bullet-proof.